# JQuery setInterval not updating on Firefox, Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I am having issues with the following code on Internet Explorer and Firefox. It functions correctly in Safari and Chrome.

The issue is that it will refresh ONCE, then never again.

```
<img class="cameras" src="http://www.redlodge.com/webcam_rlm/netcam.jpg&t=">

<script type="text/javascript">    

  function updateCamera() {
    time = new Date().getTime();
    $('.cameras').each(function() {
      var url = $(this).attr('src').replace(/&t=\d*/, '&s='+time);
      $(this).attr('src', url);
    })
  }

$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(updateCamera, 2000);
});

</script>
```

I researched and researched, and thought it was due to too many requests. Is that the case? I thought I was preventing that with "setInterval."

Comment: What issues are you having?

Comment: var time = new Date().getTime();

Comment: I see. your regexp only matches something in the url the first time, after that, it no longer matches because you replaced it with `&s=` rather than `&t=`, therefore it starts just pulling from cache. Technically your script is functioning correctly in IE and Firefox, and incorrectly in Safari and Chrome, but it isn't doing what you wanted it to do due to the logic error (or is that a typo?)

Comment: Sorry, updated - it's only refreshing once.

Comment: Thank you Kevin B. You are correct. It's working great now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it's `&t=time`, then it's `&s=time`, you need decide which one to use, as of right now only the first empty `&t=time` is replaced, not the other ones that starts with `&s=*`:

```
<img class="cameras" src="http://www.redlodge.com/webcam_rlm/netcam.jpg?s=">
```

and JS

```
function updateCamera() {
    var time = new Date().getTime();
    $('.cameras').each(function() {
      this.src = this.src.replace(/\?s=\d*/, '?s='+time);
    })
}
```

and the querystring should start with ?, not &, otherwise it wont work at all.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LZHVN/2/)

Comment: What a silly error on my part. Thank you for spending your time on this, I can't believe that I missed that. Thank you.